# Time Complexity - While loop divided by 2 with for loop nested

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I am stuck on a review question for my upcoming midterms, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Please see function below:

```
void george(int n) {                
    int m = n;                              //c1 - 1 step
    while (m > 1)                           //c2 - log(n) steps
    {                       
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)         //c3 - log(n)*<Stuck here>
          int S = 1;                        //c4 - log(n)*<Stuck here>
        m = m / 2;                          //c5 - (1)log(n) steps
    }
}
```

I am stuck on the inner for loop since i is incrementing and m is being divided by 2 after every iteration.

If m = 100:
1st iteration m = 100: loop would run 100, i iterates 100 times + 1 for last check
2nd iteration m = 50: loop would run 50 times, i iterates 50 times + 1 for last check
..... and so on

Would this also be considered log(n) since m is being divided by 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

External loop executes `log(n)` times
Internal loop executes `n + n/2 + n/4 +..+ 1 ~ 2*n` times  (geometric progression sum)
Overall time is `O(n + log(n)) = O(n)`

---

Note - if we replace `i < m` with `i < n` in the inner loop, we will obtain `O(n*log(n))` complexity, because in this case we have `n + n + n +.. + n` operations for inner loops, where number of summands is `log(n)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick reply! However, I have one quick question. From my lectures, I thought we were supposed to multiply the inner loop with the outer loop to get the time complexity ~ O(n*log(n)). Please let me know if this is not the case for this function.

Comment: We multiply when iteration count  doesn't change. Multiplication `Inner * Outer` is equal to `Inner + Inner + Inner...` - outer times. But here sum contains distinct summands.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!